# CCLocation manager -- startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges

Tags: iphone, ios4, background, gps, cllocationmanager

I have tried using `CLLocationManager`'s `startUpdatingLocation` and `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` methods seperately to get notified on location changes when application is in background. The delegate

```
 - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
        didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
               fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
```

gets triggered fine.

If i use the first one I am getting updated regularily.

If I use the later I have got only one location update and after that I have terminated the application and gone for location check for about 15 kilometers for the change in mobile towers. I have not even got one location update.

How to solve this issue ?

All I want is to  report the current location of the user to the server when there is a significant change in users location.

Please let me know if there is a way to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

Dont terminate your application. When you use significant location change, your app is suspended by the OS when there is no update in location not terminated. There is a difference between two states. Suspended app can be called to background running state when there is an update in location but terminated app cannot be.